# Does Mogg Sentry gain +2/+2 for each spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing with a friend who has [Mogg Sentry](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mogg%20Sentry) on the field I then play [Champion of the Parish](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Champion%20of%20the%20Parish) and [Vexing Devil](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vexing%20Devil).  Does Mogg Sentry become a 5/5 creature until end of turn or is it just a 3/3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mogg Sentry becomes a 5/5 until end of turn. Mogg Sentry's ability triggers once for each occurrence of "opponent casts a spell."

> 603.2c An ability triggers only once each time its trigger event occurs. However, it can trigger repeatedly if one event contains multiple occurrences. See also rule 509.4.

Answer (score 3):

To play a non-land card is to cast it.

> 701.11b To play a card means to play that card as a land or to cast that card as a spell, whichever is appropriate.

You cast two spells, so [Mogg Sentry](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mogg%20Sentry)'s ability triggers twice.

> 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. [...]

Each resolves to create a continuous effects granting itself +2/+2. As such, Mogg becomes a 5/5 until the end of the turn.

Comment: If you want the step by step description of what happens, let me know and I'll oblige.